# Flex Box in Android and Safari browsers

Tags: android, html, css, safari, flexbox

I have a wonderful problem, to don’t say otherwise.

Look this site (he is in portuguese, but the code are in english).

http://filmseasy.com/nepes/ (sorry about domain, but I needed somewhere for host)

I’m finalizing the menu and all its responsive ways. But, in chrome, or firefox and other browsers except the safari, on PC, all website look great, and exactly the way I wanted.

But in android native browsers, I’m having serious problems with the flex box.

In my code, on tablet-style.css, you will see that I put just the flex command in .flex css class, but I say that has put the vendors prefix, and still the same thing happens, =[. I left so that you may see more clearly.

Put in this website, http://mattkersley.com/responsive/, and see how works and how resolutions should appear.

And please, look on Android device, and see the difference in view.

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your `.logo` class you need to give it a `-webkit-box-flex` property to make it grow, and the element must be `display: block`

```
display: block;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
```

Safari for Windows PCs is quite old, so it uses the old Flexbox spec, as does iOS 6 and most Androids.

Comment: Man, THANK YOU SO MUCH! You saved my life man!!! I posted everything that was forum and nobody could answer. Something so simple. I had already put the -webkit-box-flex: 1, but I did not notice this detail, and the worst is that now makes perfect sense!! The <a> element is a inline and a <div> is block. So I need to do this for to work fine. Am I right? Really man, thank you so much!